# Eclipse getting closed regularly

Tags: eclipse, unhandled-exception, permgen

I have a machine with 2GB of RAM.
Currently, my Eclipse is getting closed regularly after throwing:

```
Unhandled event loop exception
PermGen space
```

Some times it gets closed without showing any error, or some other errors.

Here is the setting that I have in `eclipse.ini`:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx384m
```

What changes do I need to make to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add at the end of your eclipse.ini file this line:

```
 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Comment: Now after couple of hours after this fix...I am facing the same issue :(

Comment: increase the maxpermsize from 256 to 512mb or something. In our organisation we need around 750+ mb in maxpermsize. The number depends on your installation and usage

Comment: Raise the limit to 386 MB first, and if that doesn't help you, up it to 512. This probably means that you have many plugins installed. do you need all of them at the same time?

Comment: Below are my current settings .. still facing same issue...after regular interval... any suggestions please

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx384m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: -Xmx384m - That looks a bit low for a setup with 512 MB permGen space... I would suggest either turning off plugins that you don't use, or start with a fresh Eclipse installation and install only those plugins that you will actually use in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot.I made it 512 and got it worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  When responding to a question, please make sure it is an answer.  I realize you can't comment yet, but when you can, please don't answer a question with Thanks.